# Windows 10 Dual Boot: Default to Restarting OS

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader

I have 2 drives, each with Windows 10 installed. Before this morning, I would use the BIOS to switch between the drives and boot into the desired OS. Unfortunately, I chose the OS that was not set as the default, Windows pushed an update and restarted into the default, and somehow this bricked my OS. This is the 3rd time this has happened so Ive started learning how to use boot loaders.

I now am using Windows boot manager, but it seems I am still at risk. There is still a default and the manager doesnt seem smart enough to auto-boot into the OS that restarted. Example: Default is OS1. I am in OS2. I restart, I would like the manager to automatically boot into OS2. Instead, it loads the default.

Does this feature exist? If not, will Windows boot manager protect me from the damage caused by an auto restart after an OS update?